# Use Magnetic Card Reader With Visual Basic 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, magnetic-cards

Hi i am trying to make a program that can get information form a magnetic card reader to fill in a text box like an id and/or password. or make a new account.  i am using a MagTek SureSwipe Card Reader 21040140? How can I do that????

Comment: Okay, make it so!  Next time ask a question.

Comment: Look into USB HID.  There are a handful of .NET libraries available for this.  I've worked with this very same card reader.  Once you are reading the HID data, echo it out to the console and you will see that it reads the tracks as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow these easy steps:

1. Read the documentation on MagTek SureSwipe Card Reader 21040140
2. If you still don't know, ask a new question about how to go about this. Make sure it has some code.